# Image of a 2-sphere by a differential map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I was reading this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1923684/737974 and I can't quite get it.

-Why does the user define that the four equations?

-Why does $(2) - (4)$ implies that $xy, yz, zx \geq 0$?

-Why does $(1)$ implies that $x, y, z \geq 0$?

Thank you very much!